# Highlight errors in Terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal, jekyll, rsync

I had a problem with Terminal a Jekyll install but I didn't spot the site being not-uploaded to the server by rsync because I didn't see an error in the output. So, I was wandering:
**Is there any way to make Terminal detect errors and give them a specific color?**

My error here was:

```
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]
```

It had other things, but if this line was highlighted, I would have spotted it way earlier.

Comment: Terminal has no idea what is an error and what is good text. It's just an IO device. SEARCH for ANSI color codes and Ruby.

Comment: @theTinMan So, isn't there any way to detect if the output has «error» and highlight that line or, at least, the word in another color?

Comment: You can write code in many languages to look for key phrases and then format them, where the formatting just happens to be the ANSI codes for the look you want.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, color output is a responsibility of a program and not a terminal.

For example, clang compiler produces colorful error and warning messages.

If the application you are using does not support this, the only option is to create a wrapper and parse its output, highlighting errors in different color. This approach is taken by colorgcc, for instance, to make GCC compiler output in colors.

Perhaps you can grab that script and adjust it for your needs? Check it out here - https://github.com/colorgcc/colorgcc

Also, if there are errors, the app should probably exit with non-zero exit code. It might be a good idea to check it and write an even bigger and noticeable message upon exit in case of errors.

Hope it helps.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can enable highlighting of errors for one command with [the `hilite` utility](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hilite/). It only works for commands you type `hilite` for – it isn’t enabled globally – but it’s still useful if you know or suspect that a command outputs errors and you want to locate them. So when you build with `jekyll`, you could do any of the following:

- Change `jekyll …` to `hilite jekyll …` in your build script
- Try to remember to always type `hilite` before `jekyll`
- Run `jekyll` normally, but if its output or exit code makes you suspect you got errors, run it again with `hilite` to locate them

On OS X, you can install `hilite` with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) using [`brew install hilite`](http://braumeister.org/formula/hilite).